# gitlab "correct" way to restore deleted branch

Tags: gitlab

I noticed that one of important branches in our project was deleted on remote. I have local copy of this branch and can push it to remote, but I'm not sure that it's a "best" or "correct" way to restore it.
There are two ways:

- From UI

> 1. From the Web UI, go to Repository > Commits
> 2. Find the commit you want and copy the SHA to your clipboard
> 3. Go to Repository > Branches
> 4. Click "New Branch"
> 5. Enter a branch name
> 6. Click the "Create from" drop-down menu and enter the commit SHA. Press enter to apply it.
> 7. Click "Create Branch"

- from console:

> 1. Find the SHA1 ID of the branch's last commit by running `git reflog`
> 2. Create a new branch with the same name, based on that commit:
>    `git checkout -b <branchname> <sha1>`
> 3. Push the new branch to GitLab

Question: How to restore it in best and correct way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the processes you list will result in exactly the same result. Essentially, both are doing the same thing with a different UI: creating a new branch with the original name, pointing at a chosen commit.

The only thing that would make a difference is if there are rules in GitLab that cover that branch. For instance, if it is not allowed to push directly to some branches, the rule for that branch name might still exist, and you won't be able to push a branch created locally. In that case, creating through the GitLab UI might be the only method allowed.

Comment: thank you ! Are there any other methods/options?